# jQuery .post/.ajax loading problems

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to allow a page to initially load while allowing a synchronous ajax post call to run.

I have tried using $.post but this will not return my output in the order specified.  It returns whatever is loaded first.  Is there a way to load synchronously while still allowing the page to load?

Here are my two examples:
Example 1 **$.post**

```
var count = 20;
for(var i = 0; i<=count; i++){
    $.post("page.php", {variables: variables}, function(data){
        $('.container').append(data);
        var card = $('.card').last();
        card.children('.image').append(i);
    });
}
```

and 
Example 2 **$.ajax**

```
var count = 20;
for(var i = 0; i<=count; i++){
    $.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            page: page, 
            count: count,
            idx: i  
        },
        async: false,
    }).done(function(data){
        $('.container').append(data);
        var card = $('.card').last();
        card.children('.image').append(i);
    });
}
```

They both "Work" in the sense that they pull everything I need from the right place and it displays the correct information.  With the first example, it loads randomly.  Whatever it can load first displays first.  even inside the post, where I `append(i)`, I get the number `21` appended to everything.  Like it's gone through the loop (asynchronously) and places the last `i` (being 21) in every element.

The second example works exactly the way I would like but of course since it's `async:false` it will not load the page until it's done loading each element.

How can I get the best of both worlds and load **in order** without waiting for the page to load?  What am I missing here?

Comment: is there a way to load syncronously while doing it asyncronously? not sure I understand your question

Comment: I don't mind it LOADING async, as long as it displays in the correct order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has only function level scope. This means that the `i` variable is shared amongst iterations inside your `for` loop. When the callbacks for each iteration execute *some time later*, the (shared) `i` has reached 21 (as you've noticed).

This is a common problem with JavaScript, and can only be fixed by introducing a new level of scope into your loop.

In terms of ensuring they execute in order; Kevins answer is a clean way of deferring execution until *all* have completed. The way below should execute them in the order they were sent, as they arrive.

```
function doPost(j) {
    $.post("page.php", {variables: variables}, function(data){
        completed[j] = data;

        // Check all the responses have been received for the
        // previous AJAX requests. If we're missing some, bail.
        for (var k=0;k<j;k++) {
            if (!completed[k]) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // If we reach here, our AJAX request has been holding
        // up the show. Execute this, and all successive AJAX
        // requests which have been received.
        for (var k=j;k<completed.length && completed[k];k++) {
            $('.container').append(completed[k]);
            var card = $('.card').last();
            card.children('.image').append(k);                
        }
    });
}

var count = 20;
var completed = new Array(count);
for(var i = 0; i<=count; i++){
    doPost(i);
}
```

A way to do this with Deferreds (purely for fun and untested, but ends up cleaner (arguably) and <strike>should</strike> might work) is;

```
var reqs = [];
var count = 20;

function doPost(i, pendingDeferreds) {
    pendingDeferreds.unshift($.post("page.php", {variables: variables}));

    return jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, pendingDeferreds).done(function (data) {
        data = data[0];

        $('.container').append(data);
        var card = $('.card').last();
        card.children('.image').append(i);
    });
};

for(var i = 0; i<=count; i++){
    reqs.push(doPost(i, reqs.slice(0, i)));
}
```

Comment: I've started to rewrite all of my code and I've come into this problem where I might have less than 20 pieces of information (called from the `.post`).  Is there a way to stop this post if there is no information call back?

Comment: @ntgCleaner: you should be just able to change the "count" variable to the number of responses you need?

Comment: Unfortunately, This is evolving into a filtering and searchable Q&A section and I won't always know the number of cards.  All I will know is the maximum amount of cards per the pagination.  When the page initially loads, it will show everything, but if I filter out or search specifics, it could possibly show any number between 1 and 20.  I'd like to be able to stop the ajax process when there is no data returned.

Comment: @ntgCleaner: Mmmm, the problem is that this solution launches all AJAX requests immediately; you don't know whether any data is returned for a certain card until requests after that has been requested. Your options are to either make requests sequentially (but then the time taken to retrieve 20 cards will be (20 * response time) rather than simply response time), or to just request the 20, and drop the ones after what you need. (Ideally however, you'd be able to calculate how many cards you need...).

Answer (score 0):

Deferred objects.

```
var count = 20;
var promiseArr = []; // stores promise objects

for(var i = 0; i<=count; i++){
    // push promise objects onto promise array
    promiseArr.push($.ajax({
        url: "scripts/collective/getCards.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            page: page, 
            count: count,
            idx: i  
        }
    }));
}

// when all promise objects in array are resolved, do stuff
$.when.apply($,promiseArr).done(function(){
    // arguments for each request are passed as a single argument, here i iterate over them one by one, in order that they were sent, not received.
    $.each(arguments,function(i,args){
        var data = args[0];
        $('.container').append(data);
        $('.card').children('.image').text(i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This just about does it, though It loaded over and over again.  I think I ended up with over 100 elements instead of 21.

Comment: odd... i don't know what would cause that.

Comment: me Either.  I was tweaking the code to find out what was going on, but it was still adding several more than needed.